# Combining layer groups and additional layers in OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers

I have a layer group (mapLayers) which contains multiple layers. I want to add a VectorLayer to the map so I will be able to draw features on the map. I am able to add my layers into the map perfectly fine, but when I include the variable of VectorLayer (vector) into the new map, everything disappears.
I have also attempted to include the VectorLayer inside the layer group but this also makes the map disappear.

Any idea why this might be happening and how I can include the VectorLayer in the map without everything disappearing?

```
const mapLayers = [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  }),
    new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8085/geoserver/ny/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'ny:buildings'},
      ratio: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver',
    }),
  }), 
      new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8085/geoserver/ny/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'ny:streets'},
      ratio: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver',
    }),
];

const source = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    'stroke-color': '#ffcc33',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    'circle-radius': 7,
    'circle-fill-color': '#ffcc33',
  },
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [mapLayers, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [1468661, 7500078],
    zoom: 12,
  }),
});
```

In the example code above, everything disappears. However, if I just remove the vector from const map layers (example below), everything shows up fine, but I am not consequently able to retain/save the drawn vector features on a map.

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: mapLayers,
  target: 'map',
```

Comment: @TomazicM this worked perfectly! If you post this comment into a post, I can approve it as a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapLayers` is an array of layers, so you cannot combine it with single layer `vector` in expression `[mapLayers, vector]`. To get combined array of layers, you can for example use `mapLayers.concat([vector])`.

So relevant part of the code would then look like this:

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: mapLayers.concat([vector]),
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [1468661, 7500078],
    zoom: 12,
  }),
});
```